# Cannot implicitly convert 'byte[]' to 'byte'

Tags: c#, .net

My given code has an error of type conversion

```
 int imglength = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength;
 byte imgarray=new byte[imglength];
```

Comment: `byte` is not the same thing as `byte[]`.  The first one is a byte, the second is an array of bytes.  Try `byte[] imgarray = new byte[imglength];`

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to assign an array of bytes (`byte[]`) to a single byte, hence the error.

Try the following code:

```
byte[] imgarray = new byte[imglength];
```

Answer (score 4):

you can not assign a byte array to byte

try this

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[imglength];
```

Answer (score 1):

Structure is like this

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[imglength];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```
int imageSize = fuImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
System.IO.Stream imageStream = fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream;
byte[] imageContent = new byte[imageSize];
int status = imageStream.Read(imageContent, 0, imageSize);
```

This code coverts postedfile to byte stream

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
int imgLength = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength;
byte[] revLength= BitConverter.GetBytes(imgLength);
Array.Reverse(revLength);
byte[] imgLengthB = revLength;
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!